# Why isn't turnCount updating?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a tic-tac-toe game. As you can imagine I simply have a table with three rows and nine data-cells in my html so I won't bother posting that, but for some reason the first function I have in my script(the one that updates turnCount) doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```
var X = 'X';
var O = 'O';
var currentPlayer;
var turnCount = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td').click(function () {
        turnCount += 1;
    });
});

var setCurrentPlayer = function () {
    if (turnCount % 2 === 0) {
        currentPlayer = O;
    } else {
        currentPlayer = X;
    }
};
setCurrentPlayer();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td').click(function () {
        $(this).text(currentPlayer);
    });
});
```

Comment: have tried to print the value of turnCount inside the fn after setting it using console.log or alert?

Comment: For one thing, put your two `td click` statements together into one statement.

Comment: why do you need `$('td').click(function () ` function in two different places?

Comment: @Rinku I didn't think of that, but I just did and it is in fact updating which means that something is wrong with my setCurrentPlayer function.
Thanks.

Comment: yes u r calling that fn. only once that's y it is not updating the result. call it just after the setting turnCount..u will get the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `setCurrentPlayer();` every time you clicking `td`.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td').click(function () {
        turnCount += 1;
        setCurrentPlayer();
        $(this).text(currentPlayer);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yup, that did it thanks!
And thank you to everyone for showing me how to shorten my code by not rewriting the td function twice!